# package wallpaper for landscape, latex

Tags: graphics

I'm using [`wallpaper`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wallpaper) package to put background image on each page. I'm facing problem to put image on landscape on right position. I need to put it upper left corner of the page. I It seems that it is not rotating with landscape.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pst-all} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\begin{document}

\URCornerWallPaper{0.20}{Grafik/AA_Logo.jpg}
.
.
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
.
.
\newpage

...
\end{landscape}

\newpage
.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is rotating with the page.

Note that your code puts the image in the `upper right` corner. Not the upper left.
I've put it in the upper left corner for all pages.

You need to clear the wallpaper, and redefine it for the landscape pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage[pdftex,demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}

\ULCornerWallPaper{0.20}{Grafik/AA_Logo.jpg}
.
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\ClearWallPaper
\LLCornerWallPaper{0.20}{Grafik/AA_Logo.jpg}
.
\newpage

...
\end{landscape}
\ClearWallPaper
\ULCornerWallPaper{0.20}{Grafik/AA_Logo.jpg}
\newpage
.

\end{document}
```

Note that the `demo` option for graphicx is just used to introduce the fake black images.
It is not necessary in the actual code and should be removed.